# replacing a number with a string in a list with 'for'loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a beginner in python and I'm stuck on a task I need to complete.
I need to define a function that returns a list in a given range in which every time the number 7 appears or the number % 7 == 0 (no remainder), it is replaced with the word 'BOOM', otherwise the number returns the same. is needs to be done using the 'for' loop.

its supposed to look like this:

```
print(seven_boom(17))
['BOOM', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'BOOM', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'BOOM', 15, 16, 'BOOM']
print(seven_boom(17))
```

this is what ive tried and i have no idea what to do (end_number is the end of the range in the list but it needs to be included):

```
def seven_boom(end_number):
 list = [range(0, end_number + 1)]
 for i in list:
   if i % 7 == 0 or i[0:] == 7:
     i+=1
     return list.replace(7, 'BOOM')
```

Comment: First, of all, don't name your variables with names that are already used by the language, like `list`
Second, to create a list from a range object use `list(range(...))`

Comment: `i[0:] == 7` is always `False`: `i[0:]` is a list.

Comment: It is great you've shown what you have tried to do. Now explain what your solution is actually doing and why that isn't what you expected it to do. Figure out what parts of it aren't working, then ask specific questions about those parts you're having difficulty with (rather than just an entire homework question). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
end_number = 18
def seven_boom(end_number):
    List = range(0, end_number + 1)
    boomList = ["BOOM" if (x%7 == 0) or ("7" in str(x)) else x for x in List ]
    return boomList
```

Comment: You might want to change a condition since it doesnt take into account numbers with a 7 in it others than 7 (like 17 in the example output). For example your first condition could be `if '7' in str(x)` instead of `x==7`

Comment: Yup, you're right, updated with that

Answer (score 1):

I think this can answer your question.

```
 listEx= [x for x in range (1,20)] ## creates a list using ints from 1 to 19


def changeList(listex): # get a list as a parameter
text = 'boom' # you can change the text its the element to implement if condition meets
listnew = [item if item % 7 !=  0 and '7' not in str(item) else text for item in listex ] # checks if number is divisible by 7 and changes the appending element
return listnew # return the changed list
```

it can be done simpler and cleaner but for now it should be enough.
Also check list comprehensions in python [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: Your answer doesnt take into account when the number itself contains a '7'. Like for 17 in the example output.

Comment: wow sorry i kinda missed that part i will change the code in a sec.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure someone will edit it but next time use the curly brackets to make code easy to read. Also don't use "list" as a variable name as it is a keyword in Python. List will convert your data into a list form. I don't think leaving range in the square brackets is a good idea.

```
word = []
def seven_boom(end_number):
    numbers = list(range(0, end_number + 1))

    for i in numbers:
        if i % 7 ==0 or '7' in str(i):
            word.append("BOOM")
        else:
            word.append(i)
    return word
```

Comment: This needs `return word` statement at the button (watch your indents as well). Also, as Titouan L has pointed out, needs to account for if the number 7 appears in the given number. So replacing your if statement with `if i % 7 ==0 or "7" in str(i):` would work